# How can I access from one pod to another through ingress in kind?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, dnsmasq, kind

I have set up a cluster using kind and Dnsmasq, and have deployed ChartMuseum and ArgoCD on it. However, I am having trouble connecting to ChartMuseum from ArgoCD using the DNS 'chartmuseum.kind.cluster' to get the charts. Despite my efforts, the connection does not seem to work. Can anyone help me troubleshoot and fix this issue?

This is my configuration in kind and dnsmasq in my locl enviroment:

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  kubeadmConfigPatches:
  - |
    kind: InitConfiguration
    nodeRegistration:
      kubeletExtraArgs:
        node-labels: "ingress-ready=true"
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 80
    hostPort: 80
    listenAddress: 127.0.0.1 
    protocol: TCP
  - containerPort: 443
    hostPort: 443
    listenAddress: 127.0.0.1 
    protocol: TCP
- role: worker
- role: worker
```

and this is how the two deployments would be deployed

[image]

I can access both dns without problems.

I have been advised to modify the CoreDNS configuration in order to make queries to localhost. Could someone please clarify what changes I need to make to the configuration file to achieve this? or change the /etc/hosts configuration of each deployment.